# Add/Remove border on-click Android Java

Tags: java, android, image, onclick, border

I would like to know the simplest way to Add and Remove a border from an Image in Android Studio using Java. I just want the user to have the indication that he clicked the Image (which is clickable of course) without having two different .png.

Comment: Did you google that? You should find examples there. Did you try anything yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `ImageView` on `FrameLayout` and add

`android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` attribute.

```
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/myButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/my_drawable" />
            </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: @AdamSwid please approve for future searches

Comment: How do I approve? (sorry new to the site)

Comment: @AdamSwid you need just press check mark from the left of answer :)

Comment: great, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Put the Image in a layout, then pad the layout with some value you wish. set an OnClickListener to that image View, and on Click, change the background colour of the layout the Image is placed in. You can have this as an on and off toggle very easily.

Edit:-

ssh's answer is much clearer than mine. Reference his please.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a View with 1dp width before your image and make it visible whenever you need to show the border.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src=""/>
</LinearLayout>
```